# Query in vb to access db returns null after changing operating system date

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a select statement which was returning the required values but when I changed the OS date from English(US) to English(UK), it now returns null. I believe the problem is concerned with date since in the query am selecting values where the date from the database is the same as the date in a combobox but I don't know what else I can do. It almost looks like the dates in the combox and in the database are not the same and yet the date in the combobox is actually retrieved from the database and has been returning values fine until I changed the system date format. Can someone tell what can be done and also why this behavior after changing system date? Here's my select command:

```
cmd4.CommandText = _
    "SELECT sum(brought_qtty), recieved_qtty from brought_coffee, centre_weigh where brought_date=#" & _
    dtComb.Text.Trim & "#" & _
    "and crop_year=" & Today.Year & "and brought_date=weigh_date and weigh_centre='" & _
    cenComb.Text.Trim.Substring(0, 2) & "' group by recieved_qtty"`
```

`dtComb.Text`is the date value from the combobox and `brought_date` is the database date. Could there be a problem with this comparison `where brought_date=#" & dtComb.Text.Trim`? Am using vb and the database is access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this problem, you need to deal with the appropriate data types. In your case, you need to pass/set the parameter as Date type, not String. So, define the parameter of the appropriate type (OleDbParameter) and pass it to the query (OleDbCommand).

Some of the examples can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.90).aspx

Something like this:

```
...
cmd4.CommandText = "SELECT sum(brought_qtty), recieved_qtty from brought_coffee, centre_weigh where brought_date = ? and crop_year = ? and brought_date = weigh_date and weigh_centre = ? group by recieved_qtty"

cmd4.Parameters.Add("p1", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtComb.Text.Trim())
cmd4.Parameters.Add("p2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Today.Year
cmd4.Parameters.Add("p3", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cenComb.Text.Trim.Substring(0, 2)

...
```

Please note, the parameters' names do not matter but, the order of assigning them does (should match the order of ? in the SQL).

Comment: Thank you @Turman. Could you give an example of how the code could be when setting the parameter as Datatype. I've not done that before

Comment: Thank you so much. It is now working so fine. I used parametized queries like you said and I set their datatypes and all is cool now